# Field value is not printed from SAP Adobe form

Tags: sap-basis, livecycle-designer, adobe-form

I have a table `lt_recipe_data` which has `rcp_head_data` as another table having many fields from which `copied_from` is one field among them.

I am printing  all the data from table into adobe report. The report has a table of same structure and having copied from field inside it. I did bind it properly to the correct field from the interface using binding property.

But still when I am generating the report value is not printing only for that field and is printing for other fields.

I have checked the bindings, that seems perfect. Also I checked the driver program debugging values are passed correctly.

`rcp_data` data passed is perfect as debugged but still not showing data for the field `copied_from`.

Find snippet of code of driver program:

```
CALL FUNCTION lv_funcname "'/1BCDWB/SM00000061'
      EXPORTING
        /1bcdwb/docparams  = fp_docparams
        lt_table           = lt_table
        lt_spec_data       = spec_data
        lt_recipe_data     = rcp_data
      IMPORTING
        ...
```

Comment: I had a similar problem when a string of alphanumerics (no spaces or punctuation) was larger than the field I put it in and it was being pushed to "next" line (which makes it invisible). Try looking for options that control text wrapping or try to forcefully fit the content to cell. You can also test this by a short value to that field. If that's not it, copy that entire form (for testing) and delete your table and generate new one by dragging from data(i think that's the name) menu. Check if the table that is generated automatically is displayed correctly.

Comment: Agree with zero, try to check field value length and form interface output length